# Can't call a method from other classes?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++

I've one header file which is just methods, a second C++ file where those methods are implemented, and a third main file where I want to call a method from second C++ file.

I have shown on which lines the errors occur with comments.

**Root.h** file (just methods):

```
class Root
{
    //File
    public: void NewFile(void);
    public: void OpenFile(void);
    public: void SaveFile(void);
    public: void SaveAsFile(void);
    public: void Print(void);
    public: void Exit(void);

    //Edit
    public: void Undo(void);
    public: void Redo(void);
    public: void Cut(void);
    public: void Copy(void);
    public: void Paste(void);
    public: void SelectAll(void);

    //Tools
    public: void Options(void);

    //Help
    public: void About(void);
};
```

**Root.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Root.h"

using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::IO;

class Nroot : public Root
{
    void OpenFile()
    {
        OpenFileDialog^ opf = gcnew OpenFileDialog();
        opf->InitialDirectory = "C://";
        opf->Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
        if(opf->ShowDialog() == DialogResult::OK) //here is first error C3063: operator '==':  all operands must have the same enumeration type 
        {
            StreamReader^ sr = gcnew StreamReader(opf->FileName);
            MessageBox::Show(sr->ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
};
```

**Main File** (just event)

```
private: System::Void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    Nroot nr;
    nr.OpenFile; //here is second error C3867: 'WindowsFormsApplication2::Nroot::OpenFile': function call missing argument list; use '&WindowsFormsApplication2::Nroot::OpenFile' to create a pointer to member c:\users\srdjan\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\windowsformsapplication2\windowsformsapplication2\Form1.h 325
}
```

Comment: I presume by "c++.net", you mean c++-cli.

Comment: C++ with NET framework, C++.net see tags

Comment: Are you writing interop glue code? If not, it's way simpler to just use C#.

Comment: I was in C#.net 2 years, but i want to learn now C++.net.

Comment: I suggest sticking with C# .NET, the C++ .NET has no benefits over C# .NET afaik.

Comment: @user1814358, I agree with @ R. Martinho Fernande, `c++-cli` only purpose is to help writing interop code to unmanaged c++ or porting legacy projects to .Net. If you want to learn c++, you'd better learn unmanaged c++.

Comment: @Rapptz, It's easy to use to compile assemblies without craploads of P/Invoke. That's the main benefit I'm aware of.

Comment: @Rapptz But C++.net perfomance is greater than C#.net.

Comment: Ok guys, what you suggest me to use? Win32 app or QT framework?

Comment: @user1814358: I hope you'll forgive me if I'm somewhat skeptical of that claim. I suppose it could be true under a few very specific circumstances, but I wouldn't expect it in general.

Comment: @user1814358 They both compile to the same IL (at least for the managed parts in the case of C++/CLI), so you're talking bollocks.

Comment: @Jerry It’s not true. C++/CLI has the sole advantage that it makes interop possible (which in turn means that you can write part of the code in native C++, benefiting from performance improvements) but it compiles down to the same byte code as equivalent C#. There’s in general *no* difference in speed.

Comment: @JerryCoffin 
I'm not sure. :/
C++.net is very similar with C#.net, so that's why i use C++.net, but if unmanaged C++ is better, i will start learn that. :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I'm not trying to say there *is* likely to be a difference -- simply admitting that I've neither examined the internals of the compilers nor tested so exhaustively that I can absolutely rule out the possibility of a difference. I hope you'll forgive me if I entertain some doubts about whether others have done so either.

Comment: @user1814358: I don't think I'd say either managed or unmanaged is exactly "better" -- it's more a question of what you want to accomplish than of one being clearly better than the other.

Comment: So, if someone know C++/CLI let me help to solve this problem. :)

Comment: @user1814358, I think the biggest issue of c++-cli is that is has managed and unmanaged parts, that are not fully compatible with each other. Do you really want to handle _that mix_?

Comment: @Lol4t0 
i don't know really, i will see, what is better solution for windows applications(no database app, for that i use C#), is better to use Win32 applications, or QT, or something else?

Comment: @user1814358, It is subjective, I'd recommend Qt. Row Win32 api is never used now days.

Comment: @Lol4t0

Ok, thanks for suggestion, i will start with QT.

This topic can be locked. (I don't know how to lock, if that is possible)

Comment: @user1814358 By the way, Stack Overflow is not a forum. This is not a _thread_ or a _subject_, it's a _question_. Those things below? They're not messages, they're _answers_. And we don't lock things unless they're against the rules. With that said, [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Looks like `DialogResult::OK` enumeration value defined differently more then in one place, so you have to use full path to the value: `::System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK`. At least MSDn example [does so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e61ft40c.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2):

   ```
   if(opf->ShowDialog() == ::System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
   ```
2. You've forgotten parenthesis:

   ```
   nr.OpenFile();
              ^^
   ```
3. To access `Nroot::OpenFile()` outside of the class, you should make it `public`. In `c++`, private access modifier is applied to members by default:

   ```
   class Nroot : public Root
   {
   public:
       void OpenFile()
   //...
   ```

Comment: Ok, i now have just one problem, this nr.OpenFile(); don't work 

this is error:




1 IntelliSense: function "WindowsFormsApplication2::Nroot::OpenFile" (declared at line 9 of "c:\users\srdjan\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\windowsformsapplication2\windowsformsapplication2\Root.cpp") is inaccessible c:\Users\Srdjan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Form1.h 325

Comment: Now work, thank you very much. :)

P.S: This "forum" or what is this, is GREAT!!! One more time thank you.

Comment: @user1814358 Please accept the answer (the check mark at upper left corner of the answer), that's how you mark your SO question as resolved, no more answers needed.